# TimeZoneInfo conversion of DateTimeOffset fails

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, .net-7.0

In trying to convert a `DateTimeOffset` between two time zones, I've successfully used `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()`, but I found a case where the conversion doesn't work. That is - conversion between `UTC+11.00` and `UTC+10:30` which has no effect.

Here is my completely vanilla source:

```cs
public static DateTimeOffset ConvertToNewTimeZone(this DateTimeOffset dt, string newTz)
{
  var tzi = DeduceTimeZone(newTz); // converts out of proprietary format into std format
  var result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dt, tzi);
  return result;
}
```

And here's a debug view of the values of my variables.

[image: Debug View]

Notice how the result is still in `UTC+11:00`.  I expected the result to be in `10:30`.  Can anyone explain why the conversion didn't happen?  I'm not aware of any adjustments that might apply.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the daylight saving time (DST), you may know that January is summer in the southern hemisphere where Lord Howe Island is located, if you try to convert a different date in winter, the offset will be 10:30.

```
var dt = new DateTime(2022, 7, 1);
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTimeOffset(dt), tzi);
// 22/7/1 02:30:00 +10:30
```

[TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getutcoffset?view=net-7.0)

[Time zone essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/time-zone-overview#time-zone-essentials)

Comment: I am aware of the DST in AU (I live there).  The TZ difference should have resulted in some difference in the datetimeoffset.  I worked it out in the end. See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

In the end I narrowed it down when I noticed that the implementation of the TimeZoneInfo in Windows is different from that in Linux and MacOS.  My tests were inadvertently comparing local time (debugging on windows) with a different set of time zones (where I was logging from a Docker container running on AKS on Azure, which was a Linux container).

In the end, it appears that my time zone conversion defaulted to UTC, because the System Timezone Database is empty.  That is, `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Count == 0`.

Not sure what to do about it, but at least I know now why my code was failing.

Comment: On linux TimeZoneInfo requires [the ICU library](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu), have you installed it?

Comment: not yet, but I'm going to...